# For Loop creating sequential name txt file

Tags: c, file, pointers

I want to create N files in a for loop under Linux as O.S.;
This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  FILE *ptr;
  char name[25];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    snprintf(name, sizeof(name), "File_Nr%d.txt", i);
    ptr = fopen(name, "w");
    if( ptr == NULL ){
    perror("Error creating file!");
    }

    fclose(ptr);
}

return 0;
}
```

It works and creates File_Nr0.txt to File_Nr9.txt.

Question: is this code "safe"?

Comment: Just a question, maybe there is something better than I can do! :)

Comment: well in that case you could return an error if something goes wrong, and maybe consider using `"w+"`, `"a"` or `"a+"` for open mode to avoid truncating a file if it already exists

Comment: also consider including your clarification about the safety in the question

Comment: @DDBE, consider asking this question on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps since you want to only create the files, you can directly use the `open()` system call, which has more options and more readable way of expressing options IMO.

```
int fd = open(name, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC,
         S_IWUSR | S_IRUSR | S_IWGRP | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH); 
or
int fd = creat(name, 0644) // consider it to be an alias for above.
```

if you want to fail when the file exists already,

```
int fd = open(name, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_EXCL, 0644);
```

in `fopen()` you can achieve this by using the `'x'` in `mode` param.

```
ptr = fopen(name, "wx");
```

And as @xception mentioned, you should return a non-zero error code when something goes wrong.

```
if (NULL == ptr) {
  perror("...");
  return -1; // or better the errno which was set by open() call..
}
```

And in your code, you attempt to close the `ptr` even in failure case, that is gonna give you a crash. So, you need to handle that.

Comment: My bad: the `'x'`  as part of the *mode* argument to `fopen()` is described by [C11 7.21.5.3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.3).